# How to create a synchronous version of NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using `NSURLConnection` inside of an `NSIncrementalStore` to synchronize my `NSManagedObject` with rest based web service built in Rails. I am aware of `+sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error` but my understanding is that will not allow me to access such things as the HTTP response status code which I will need to properly handle the response, my understanding is sendSynchronousRequest returns the data if it responds in the 200 range and fails if it doesn't and doesn't really give you much more than that.

I'm assuming I will somehow have to block the current method call after the `NSURLConnection` is instantiated and unblock it after `NSURLConnection`'s delegate sets some value that can be returned by the blocked method.

I'm assuming this will involve some combination of NSLock and NSThread but I don't know where to start with this.

Comment: Also, it seems, is NSURLConnectionDelegate documentation available anywhere online? It does not exist outside of the header file. The documentation online seems to be only about authentication and does not have anything like `connection:didReceiveResponse:`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you cast the response object that you get from the `returningResponse:` parameter to an `NSHTTPURLResponse`, you can access the status code and other HTTP-specific response values.

```
NSURLResponse* response = nil;
NSError* error = nil;
NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                     returningResponse:&response
                                                 error:&error];
NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
if ([httpResponse statusCode] == 200) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to get me almost all the way there. It seems to work properly for a 422 but it doesn't seem to want to let me handle a 401 myself, when the server responds with a 401 the httpResponse variable in the example above is nil. Can anything be done about this or is this just a limitation I have to work around?

Comment: Sounds like you want a lower-level API than `NSURLConnection`, which is in general designed to handle stuff like that for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSError* err;
NSHTTPURLResponse* response;
NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
```

Your HTTP Response is returned by indirection, so you do have access to it. Just pass in an NSHTTPURLResponse, or cast it as such.

> I'm assuming I will somehow have to block the current method call after the NSURLConnection >is instantiated and unblock it after NSURLConnection's delegate sets some value that can be >returned by the blocked method. I'm assuming this will involve some combination of NSLock and >NSThread

I'm not sure what you mean by this. You are executing a synchronous request, there is no need for a delegate. As for the threading, since you are executing these requests synchronously you will probably want to make them on a background thread, or even simpler, using GCD. I would look into [NSOperation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSOperationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll look into this. If my understanding of NSIncrementalStore is correct I would have to make use of GCD outside of the NSIncremental store i.e. whenever I work with Core Data within the application. Hope that made sense =/ this is my first time working with obj-c